# 'U' does not refer to a value

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, clang++

I'm using [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/).

Command line is:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -O2 main.cpp && ./a.out
clang++ -std=c++11 -O2 main.cpp && ./a.out
```

The following code compiles fine in g++ but not in clang++.

```cpp
    template <typename T, typename... U>
    A& operator ()(T a, U... b)
    {
        struct Inner { 
            operator decltype(T(U...)) const {
                return a(b...);
            }
        } inner;

        return *this;
    }
```

> main.cpp:17:37: error: 'U' does not refer to a value
>
> ```
>             operator decltype(T(U...)) const {
>
>                                 ^
> ```
>
> main.cpp:13:43: note: declared here
>
> ```
>     template <typename T, typename... U>
>
>                                       ^
> ```
>
> 1 error generated.

The error I get now is:

```
main.cpp:18:41: error: reference to local variable 'a' declared in enclosing function 'operator()'
```

My class looks like this:

```
template <typename R>
class A {
        R value = R();
    public:
        A() { }
        ~A() { }
        template <typename T, typename... U>
        A& operator ()(T a, U... b)
        {
            struct Inner { 
                operator decltype(std::declval<T>()(std::declval<U>()...))() const {
                    // some code here to return a(b...)
                }
            } inner;
            value += inner;
            return *this;
        }

        R val() {
            return value;
        }
};
```

Comment: You should not just completely change your question - this makes it almost useless for people with the original problem. If you have two questions, ask them as such.

Comment: @Xeo Sorry, I wasn't sure how to describe the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The compiler is right, it refers to types, not values. You need to write:

```
operator decltype(std::declval<T>()(std::declval<U>()...))() const {
// you need       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ and ^^
    return a(b...);
}
```

(the last `()` are needed to make it a valid conversion operator of the form `operator T() const`)

That said, you can not use `a` and `b...` inside of `Inner`, so the whole example doesn't make any sense. Whatever your use-case is, the above doesn't really work, I can just show you how to fix the signature so that Clang accepts the code, but you will still be unable to use it.

---

And after your update, it's an entirely different question now. Maybe this works for you:

```
template <typename R>
class A {
    R value = R();
public:
    A() { }
    ~A() { }
    template <typename T, typename... U>
    A& operator ()(T a, U... b)
    {
        struct Inner { 
            using R2 = decltype(std::declval<T>()(std::declval<U>()...));
            R2 impl(T a, U... b) const {
                return a(b...);
            }
        } inner;
        value += inner.impl(a,b...);
        return *this;
    }

    R val() {
        return value;
    }
};
```

---

Referring to Walter's comment: You could, now that you pass the parameters, also use trailing return types:

```
struct Inner { 
    auto impl(T a, U... b) const -> decltype(a(b...)) {
        return a(b...);
    }
} inner;
```

or with C++14, you could use

```
struct Inner { 
    auto impl(T a, U... b) const {
        return a(b...);
    }
} inner;
```

Comment: Yes, you're correct, I just ran into that problem. Let me post more context in the question.

Comment: why not `decltype(a(b...))` (see my answer)?

Comment: @Walter I updated the answer to show how it could be used, but your answer is plain wrong as the syntax is illegal and you can't access `a` and `b...` from within `Inner` with no parameters to the operator.